# Git unable to identify project.pbxproj

Tags: ios, xcode, git, push

Whenever i commit and push `project.xcodeproj` file, git not able to identify `project.pbxproj` because it is not showing on remote branch.

If i do some changes in project like add a new file or change project settings etc. but still git unable to identify any changes in `project.xcodeproj`.

Please help me out.

Comment: What is in your .gitignore file? Is it ignoring the folder that your .pbxproj file is in, or is it ignoring that file itself?

Comment: @Stephen No i haven't in ignore any file in .gitignore.

Comment: What the result after  `git add `

Comment: @dengApro file added successfully

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i got the solution,
I move in `project.xcodeproj` bundle and forcefully add `project.pbxproj` file by using below command

```
git add -f project.pbxproj
```

Comment: For a couple of hours, Ive been trying to work this out, until I see this post, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because the `project.pbxproj` file is packed and embedded in the `project.xcodeproj` bundle.

You change it , and git add it.

> Git not able to identify project.pbxproj because it is not showing on
>   remote branch.

I think you need some Plugin to open file in Github, like fugitive.vim .